# pgAdmin4 Hide Alerts

Tags: pgadmin-4

pgAdmin4 has introduced 'alerts' or 'toasts' in the UI that display the status of certain tasks.

There seems to be no way to dismiss these alerts, which obscure other parts of the UI, without first clicking on the 'Click here for details' link.  This opens yet another window, which you then can close to dismiss the alert.

I've searched the docs for any mentioned of 'alert', 'notification', 'toast', etc with no luck.  I would like to know if there is a way to hide multiple alerts at once, or change their default behavior, for example to get them to disappear after a few seconds (like an Android 'toast').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to report (in case it helps anyone else) that v2 of pgAdmin 4 addresses this issue by providing a close widget in each toast that comes up.